# Null pointer exception occurs while trying to connect sonarlint to sonarqube server

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint

Hi  i am getting following error while connecting sonarlint to sonarqube server.

Having message as : Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.ui.internal.server.wizard.ServerConnectionModel.setUserOrgs(ServerConnectionModel.java:196)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.ui.internal.server.wizard.ServerConnectionWizard.tryLoadOrganizations(ServerConnectionWizard.java:290)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.ui.internal.server.wizard.ServerConnectionWizard.handlePageChanging(ServerConnectionWizard.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog$10.run(WizardDialog.java:1554)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.firePageChanging(WizardDialog.java:1551)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.doPageChanging(WizardDialog.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1186)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

Comment: It looks like a configuration issue. When did you see this issue first?